# enumerating available wireless clients c#

Tags: c#, wireless

I am researching a way to enumerate all of the wireless clients detected by a system. In brief what I'm wanting to do is have a system monitor all the wireless clients (NOT base stations) that are broadcasting, and examine the MAC addresses and possibly signal strenth.  This is to be used in conjunciton with a security system I'm devising.

It's my understanding that, ordinarily, client information for networks you are not a member of, is dumped by the wireless adapter during thier discovery.  As such you need to use an adapter that will go into promiscious mode.  I have the Riverbed AirPcap adapter that facilitates this capability, but I don't know how to go about auditing the adapter for signals it detects.

I've sucessfully used the Managed WIFI API which will report the available base station IDs detected by the card, but I can't find any documentation or anything within the API classes to support enumerating the clients either on or off your current network.

I know that such a thing is possible because there are 3rd party apps such as Cain and IStumbler can both display that type of data using a promiscious card.

Can anyone offer some advice on how to approach this?  I had also thought there might be something within Netsh or IPconfig that would do this and I could audit those to get the data I need, but alas, I can't seem to find anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'd like to use c# to develop the system if at all possible.